# How can I sort a hash's keys naturally?

Tags: perl, sorting, hash, natural-sort

I have a Perl hash whose keys start with, or are, numbers.

If I use,

```
foreach my $key (sort keys %hash) {
    print $hash{$key} . "\n";
}
```

the list might come out as,

```
0
0001
1000
203
23
```

Instead of

```
0
0001
23
203
1000
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be print $key to list the keys?

Comment: You're sorting the keys, but you're printing the values of the hash...

Comment: I recommend you look up "natural sorting."  The selected answer below by Paul Tomblin is absolutely incorrect for "natural" sort algorithms.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
foreach my $key (sort { $a <=> $b} keys %hash) {
    print $hash{$key} . "\n";
}
```

The sort operation takes an optional comparison "subroutine" (either as a block of code, as I've done here, or the name of a subroutine).  I've supplied an in-line comparison that treats the keys as numbers using the built-in numeric comparison operator '<=>'.

Comment: To clarify a bit: the keys in your case are strings, and are sorted as strings. <=> operator interprets its arguments as numbers, converting strings to numbers as needed.

This is the sense of much of perl's oddness: operators, rather than variables, are typed in perl.

Comment: It's context rather than type. <=> evaluates it's operands in numeric context, while the default sort operator (cmp) evaluates them in scalar (i.e. string) context.

Comment: @kixx: Numbers are scalars too.  A scalar is a single value, regardless of type.  That is, numbers, strings, even references are scalars, while lists and hashes are not.  "Scalar context" has little to nothing to do with this.

Comment: I think this answer is a bit misleading. Of course, it works with numbers. But this is because the `<=>` operator sorts **numerically**. This does not work with words ("Argument isn't numeric in numeric comparison"). The `cmp` operator sorts _lexically_, but see Schwern's answer for something that actually sorts _naturally_.

Comment: @basic6 did you actually read the question? He wants it sorted by the numbers that start each key.

Comment: @Paul Tomblin: Yes, and the keyword is "start" ("...keys _start_ with [...] numbers"). A key "123foo" _starts_ with a number, but it is not a number, so the `<=>` operator will not work (throw a warning). But again, the example only lists numbers (not number/word strings), so given these keys, the `<=>` operator you're suggesting is the right choice.

Comment: @basic6 `<=>` handles "123foo" just fine.

Comment: @Paul Tomblin: Not really: `Argument "123foo" isn't numeric`. That's not "just fine" to me.

Comment: `perl -e "print '123foo' <=> 123, \"\n\";"` prints `0`, no warning.

Comment: Oh, I see, I wasn't testing with "use warnings;" or `-w`. Yes, I can see that would be an annoyance.

Comment: He's sorting the keys and printing the values... We don't know what the keys look like.

Comment: The question title includes the word "naturally."  This is not natural.

Comment: You're using slabs of sand to train electricity to think. Nothing we do is "natural".

Answer (score 19):

[Paul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383528/how-can-i-sort-a-hashs-keys-naturally/383539#383539) is correct for numbers, but if you want to take it a step further and sort mixed words and numbers like a human would, neither `cmp` nor `<=>` will do. For example,

```
  9x
  14
  foo
  fooa
  foolio
  Foolio
  foo12
  foo12a
  Foo12a
  foo12z
  foo13a
```

[Sort::Naturally](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sort::Naturally) takes care of this problem, providing the `nsort` and `ncmp` routines.

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem is the body of the loop (which no other answer here seems to point out).

```
foreach my $key ( sort keys %hash ) {
    print $hash{$key} . "\n";
}
```

We don't know what the keys of `%hash` are. We just know that they that are handed to you as `$key`, in lexical order, inside the loop. You then use the keys to access the contents of the hash, printing each entry.

The *values* of the hash do not come out in a sorted order, because you sort on the *keys*.

Would you instead want to output the *values* in sorted order, consider the following loop:

```
foreach my $value ( sort values(%hash) ) {
    printf( "%s\n", $value );
}
```

This loop *does* print the values in the order you observe:

```
0
0001
1000
203
23
```

To sort them numerically instead, use

```
foreach my $value ( sort { $a <=> $b } values(%hash) ) {
    printf( "%s\n", $value );
}
```

This produces

```
0
0001
23
203
1000
```

which is what you wanted.

See [the Perl manual for the `sort` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) for further information and many more examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
$key (sort { $a <=> $b} keys %hash)
```

will do the trick

Or descending sort:

```
$key (sort { $b <=> $a} keys %hash)
```

Or even

```
$key (sort { $a <=> $b} values %hash)
$key (sort { $b <=> $a} values %hash)
```

Comment: What will the last one do? Sort by the values instead of the keys? What if the values are not unique? Unstable sort?