# The sort order is not applied

Tags: sorting, perl, hash

I need order an hash in perl. I push value in a hash. Then i need to order it. The problem is that  is not ordered. This is my code:

```
my %hash_section;
for my $y (0..$#xml) {
    if ( $xml[$y] =~m/<sezione numero="(.*?)">(.*?)<\/sezione>/i) { 
        push @{$hash_section{$xml[$y]}}, $1;            
    }
}
foreach my $i(sort {$a <=> $b} values %hash_section) {
    say Dumper(\%hash_section);
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: You can't sort arrayrefs with `<=>`... And you're just dumping the hash table inside your loop anyways instead of using `$i`...

Comment: Hashes are not ordered, but you can sort the keys like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383528/how-can-i-sort-a-hashs-keys-naturally

Answer (score 4):

Hash are inherently unordered.

You are getting the values of the elements of the hash and sorting those. Then you loop over the sorted values. But you don't actually use them (`$i`). Instead, you repeatedly dump the hash.

Maybe you want

```perl
for my $key (
   sort { $hash_section{ $a } <=> $hash_section{ $b } }
      keys( %hash_section )
) {
   say "$key: $hash_section{ $key }";
}
```

This gets the keys of the elements of the hash and sorts them by their associated value. Then, it loops over the sorted keys. For each sorted key, it prints the key and the associated value.